# excel 2016 search and replace linebreaks

Tags: excel, replace, excel-2016

I am looking for a solution how to search and replace breaks in excel 2016. I tried searching for

```
\n
```

as well as

```
ctrl + j
```

which did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two hard returns in Excel, try:

```
Sub ThePointOfNoReturn()
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String

    s1 = Chr(10)
    s2 = Chr(13)
    s3 = "whatever"
    Cells.Replace What:=s1, Replacement:=s3
    Cells.Replace What:=s2, Replacement:=s3
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Finding the *"other"* return is covered by Chris Neilsen's answer here:  [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/370066/how-to-search-for-newline-or-linebreak-characters-in-excel)

Comment: That is useful information. Is there a similar keybinding for the other hard return Chr(13). Because searching for `ctrl+j` did not work as I mentioned, so it might very well be that the breaks of type Chr(13).

Comment: @AskingQuestions  See my **EDIT#1**